# Why JavaScript return True for following condition?

Tags: javascript, string, comparison

While solving one issue, I notice following condition

```
if("String" == ["String"]) {
    console.log("Valid");
}
else
{
    console.log("Invalid");

}
```

I thought that it should log "Invalid", since first value is string and second value is object of string. But to my surprise, it is logging "Valid". Any specific reason, why this condition is true.

Comment: In JavaScript, you should always use the [strict equality](https://javascript.info/comparison#strict-equality) in caparison.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `==` to compare them, so the array is first converted to a string.

If you use `===` (which you *probably* should do always), they'll not be equal.